# How can I change the value of a textarea field using javascript to trigger button disable change?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ui-automation

I wrote an automation script for filling out these mundane forms at work and everything seems to work except for the textarea part where I'm successfully able to update the value in the field using

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input'); 
textarea.value = 'hi';
```

But this doesn't register in the code as the submit button is still disabled and I need to manually paste the text into the box for it to become clickable. Is there a way to write the function so changing the value of the text area actually adds the text with the cursor in the textarea box (replicates typing) in order to make the submit button clickable again?

Comment: you probably need to trigger the `change` event on the textarea so that it will notice the change and update the submit button.

Comment: are you searching maybe for `focus`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

Comment: @Sysix `focus()` would be to allow the user to edit the field by hand. They want to change it with code.

Comment: The OP's assumption that putting the cursor into the textarea would solve the problem is most likely wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I know, the `change` event would be the better solution, but we don't know how the other code is reacting to the change

Comment: Putting the cursor doesn't fix the problem my bad Barmer. I meant if the cursor behaviour could be recreated, aka the value is actually typed using a cursor, it would work

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to replicate user input or user paste as that would be a huge valnurebility for a browser. However you don't need to. All you need is to override the submit button behaviour. The first idea would look something like that:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('c4d981e9a2c98b0483252333_input'); 
textarea.value = 'hi';
document.getElementById('butt').removeAttribute('disabled'); // maybe a different selector would come in handy
document.getElementById('butt').click();
```